# Slick slider random autoplay speed for more sliders with same slider class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider, slick.js

I am using slick slider. I have three sliders on page, they all have same class and slick options. However I would like three different slick 'autoplaySpeed' option or add random delay on each for all three sliders instead of creating different class for every slider. Is that possible?

Three slides with same class name:

https://jsfiddle.net/x78y143f/1/

```js
$('.slider').slick({
  arrows: false,
  infinite: true,
  speed: 1000,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 2000,
  fade: true,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1
});
```

```css
.flex-row {
  display: flex;
}

.slider {
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 20px;
}

.slider div img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-row">
  <div class="slider">
    <div>
      <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz2.png" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slider">
    <div>
      <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz2.png" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz3.png" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slider">
    <div>
      <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz3.png" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Expected result (three different 'autoplaySpeed' options):

https://jsfiddle.net/x78y143f/2/

```js
$('.slider1').slick({
  arrows: false,
  infinite: true,
  speed: 1000,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 2000,
  fade: true,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1
});

$('.slider2').slick({
  arrows: false,
  infinite: true,
  speed: 1000,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 5000,
  fade: true,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1
});

$('.slider3').slick({
  arrows: false,
  infinite: true,
  speed: 1000,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 8000,
  fade: true,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1
});
```

```css
.flex-row {
  display: flex;
}

.slider1,
.slider2,
.slider3 {
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 20px;
}

.slider1 div img,
.slider2 div img,
.slider3 div img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-row">
  <div class="slider1">
    <div>
      <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz2.png" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slider2">
    <div>
      <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz2.png" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz3.png" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slider3">
    <div>
      <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz3.png" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like that all three sliders have different start of slide change (slides in each slider do not have to change randomly).

Comment: you could use an [each loop](https://api.jquery.com/each/) and initiate each one with a random speed

Comment: Could you please post some code and show how to do that. I am new to javascript so I would not know how to do that but I understand what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an [each loop](https://api.jquery.com/each/) on your original selector

```js
$('.slider').each(function(index) {
  var randomSpeed = 1000 * (index + 1);  // code to calculate random speed here

  $(this).slick({
    arrows: false,
    infinite: true,
    speed: 1000,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: randomSpeed,
    fade: true,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1
  });
});
```

If you need to generate a proper random number, have a look at [`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)

Comment: When I try to implement your code sliders do not work any more:

https://jsfiddle.net/s0hp5koj/

Comment: typo I missed the `.` before the `each` - see edit: https://jsfiddle.net/x78y143f/1/